# Average of characters and average of words per line in a file w/o using .split()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
with open('File123.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()

    print(sum(len(line) for line in lines)/len(lines))

f.close()
```

How I can calculate the average number of characters per line and average number of words per line? My current code only does one of them. I can't use the function split() to do this. I'm at a lost and need some assistance.

Comment: Can you edit your question to give an example input?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/acosuzorem.swift Here's another code I tried. I think this will be easier to explain. How can I use this code here to calculate the average characters per line and average words per line in a text file?

Comment: That code Print the Number of Characters in Each Line and Non-space characters of each line. How can I modify it to calculate those two averages?

Comment: Your code already calculates the number of characters per line, if don't want to count white spaces you can just use `line.replace(' ', '')`. I'm asking for a sample input because if you can't use `str.split()` to count the number of words, then you either need a complicated tokenizer or regex solution. And we can not give you one unless we see what your data looks like.

Comment: The output for the above code is 32.348837209302324, but Im not sure what the output for the average word per lines